# Why is my calculation of percentage .12 off?

Tags: c

I am in programming 1 right now. I am creating a program that is meant to show the calculation of a teachers discount (12%) on a total purchase amount. When printing the amount of the discount on screen based on purchase total, I am coming up with an incorrect total. Here is the Code:

```
double total_b4_tax;
printf("\nEnter the purchase total : ");
scanf("%lf", &total_b4_tax);
getchar ();


if (teach_music == 'y' || 'Y')
{
    double discount_total = teach_music * .12;
    printf("Total purchase                  $   %.2lf\n", total_b4_tax);
    printf("Discount total                  $   %.2lf\n", discount_total);
}
```

My discount total is coming to 14.52 when in actuality 122.0 * .12 is 14.64. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: Your code is not complete as it does not compile. Also this line looks wrong: `double discount_total = teach_music * .12;`

Comment: You meant `double discount_total = total_b4_tax * .12;`

Comment: This `if (teach_music == 'y' || 'Y')` is not a valid line in C. (It is, but it does not do what you think it does.)

Comment: @RadLexus Darn, I missed that one.

Comment: Surely this is a rigged question.... so she just happens to be entering a value very close to the ASCII value of 'Y'. And never thought to test any other vlaues. Incredible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to calculate a discount by multiplying a character with a float:

```
double discount_total = teach_music * .12;
```

before that, you made sure that `teach_music` is 'y' or 'Y'. Im curious how that compiled, and how C comes to the conclusion that 'y' or 'Y' is 121.

**EDIT:** Harr, 'Y' is ASCII 121. So multiplying that with .12 results in 14.52

Anyway, I assume that

```
 double discount_total = total_b4_tax * .12;
```

makes it all better.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems so obvious now!